# Duplicate key row insert error on delete statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am executing the following `DELETE` statement in SQL, but am getting the below error message.

```
DELETE PSRO
FROM ROLEUSER PSRO
INNER JOIN PS_GH_AD_X_WALK B ON B.OPRID = PSRO.ROLEUSER
INNER JOIN HSDEV185.HSDEV92B.dbo.PS_JOB C ON C.EMPLID = B.GH_AD_EMPLID AND B.GH_AD_EMPLID <> ''
WHERE C.EFFDT = 
(SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM HSDEV185.HSDEV92B.dbo.PS_JOB A_ED 
WHERE C.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID 
AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 


Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Procedure ROLEUSER_TR, Line 67
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.AUDIT_ROLEUSR' with unique index 'AUDIT_ROLEUSR'. The duplicate key value is (Native SQL                    , Apr 23 2019  1:15PM, D).
The statement has been terminated.
```

I am confused why SQL is interpreting my `DELETE` command as an insert?

**EDIT:**
There is the following trigger associated with ROLEUSER table. I'm not very familiar with triggers. Is there a way to prevent the insert from occuring when this Delete is executing via SQL (as opposed from a delete occuring online in a system, which is what the trigger was intended to be used for) ?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PSROLEUSER_TR] ON [dbo].[ROLEUSER]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @XTYPE CHAR(1), @OPRID CHAR(30)
SET @OPRID = NULL
SELECT @OPRID = case (charindex(',',
cast(context_info as char(128))))
when 0 then 'Native SQL'
else 
substring(cast(context_info as
CHAR(128)),1,(charindex(',',cast(context_info as char(128)))-1))
end
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = @@spid
-- Determine Transaction Type
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
BEGIN
SET @XTYPE = 'D'
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
BEGIN
IF (@XTYPE = 'D')
 BEGIN
  SET @XTYPE = 'U'
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
  SET @XTYPE = 'I'
 END
END
-- Transaction is a Delete
IF (@XTYPE = 'D')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO PS_AUDIT_PSROLEUSR
(AUDIT_OPRID,AUDIT_STAMP,AUDIT_ACTN,
ROLEUSER,
ROLENAME,
DYNAMIC_SW)
SELECT @OPRID,getdate(),'D',
ROLEUSER,
ROLENAME,
DYNAMIC_SW FROM deleted 
END
-- Transaction is a Insert
IF (@XTYPE = 'I')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO PS_AUDIT_PSROLEUSR
(AUDIT_OPRID,AUDIT_STAMP,AUDIT_ACTN,
ROLEUSER,
ROLENAME,
DYNAMIC_SW)
SELECT @OPRID,getdate(),'A',
ROLEUSER,
ROLENAME,
DYNAMIC_SW FROM inserted 
END
-- Transaction is a Update
IF (@XTYPE = 'U')
BEGIN
-- Before Update
INSERT INTO PS_AUDIT_PSROLEUSR
(AUDIT_OPRID,AUDIT_STAMP,AUDIT_ACTN,
ROLEUSER,
ROLENAME,
DYNAMIC_SW)
SELECT @OPRID,getdate(),'K',
ROLEUSER,
ROLENAME,
DYNAMIC_SW FROM deleted 
-- After Update
INSERT INTO PS_AUDIT_PSROLEUSR
(AUDIT_OPRID,AUDIT_STAMP,AUDIT_ACTN,
ROLEUSER,
ROLENAME,
DYNAMIC_SW)
SELECT @OPRID,getdate(),'N',
ROLEUSER,
ROLENAME,
DYNAMIC_SW FROM inserted 
END
```

Comment: Is there any triggers on your tables?

Comment: IT SEEMS  you shared part of query cause dbo.AUDIT_ROLEUSR this table is not avail in this query

Comment: @rad Yes there is a trigger on the table. I edited the post above. Not sure if I can alter it to allow the delete to occur through SQL without the subsequent insert?

Comment: It must be another trigger, named `ROLEUSER_TR1`.

Comment: Would this be a situation where using a cursor would help process each row individually?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
alter index AUDIT_ROLEUSR on TableName
    rebuild with (ignore_dup_key = on)
```

or check your procedure ROLEUSER_TR on Line 67 and make sure there is no triggers.

**EDIT:**

If you want to perform this removal regularly, you can create a procedure that will disable index, do the deletion and turn it back on.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prevent the insert from occuring when this Delete is executing via SQL (as opposed from a delete occuring online in a system

Not directly, no.  But you can code the trigger to take no action in some circumstances.  For instance if you add this to the start of the trigger:

```
if user_id() = 1 return;
```

It will exit immediately when DBO (the database owner or a sysadmin) runs a command, but run the trigger body for anyone else.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Would this be a situation where using a cursor would help process each row individually?